# how to put public class inside switch case

Tags: java, android

Inside public class we want switchcase based on package name in every case we are calling one public URL.. i tried this way it is not working switch case

```
public class AllChanges {

    Context context;
Switch(getPackageName()) {
        case "com.agilerise.package1":
            public static String gurl = "http://google.com/index.php";

            break;

        case "com.agilerise.package2":
public static String gurl = "http://bing.com/index.php";
  case "com.agilerise.package2":
public static String gurl = "http://stackoverlfow.com/index.php";

            break;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class AllChanges {
 public static String gurl ="";
 public void seturl()
 {
  Switch(getPackageName()) {
        case "com.agilerise.package1":
        gurl = "http://google.com/index.php";
        break;
    case "com.agilerise.package2":
        gurl = "http://bing.com/index.php";
        break;
    case "com.agilerise.package2":
        gurl = "http://stackoverlfow.com/index.php";
        break;
 }
 }

}
```

call like this

```
 AllChanges  allchanges=new AllChanges();
 allchanges.seturl();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read about `scope`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3

You need to declare your variables in the class scope. And your switch case has to be within a function. Your example has a duplicated case, you should probably fix that. `com.agilerise.package1`, `com.agilerise.package2`, `com.agilerise.package3`

```
public class AllChanges {

    public static String gurl = "";

    Context context;
    private void myFunction(){
        switch(getPackageName()) {
            case "com.agilerise.package1":
                gurl = "http://google.com/index.php";
                break;
            case "com.agilerise.package2":
                gurl = "http://bing.com/index.php";
                break;
            case "com.agilerise.package3":
                gurl = "http://stackoverlfow.com/index.php";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a more elegant solution. You should try to avoid static variables. You could then call this function by `String url = getUrl(myFunction());`

```
private String getUrl(String s){
    switch(s) {
        case "com.agilerise.package1":
            return "http://google.com/index.php";
        case "com.agilerise.package2":
            return "http://bing.com/index.php";
        case "com.agilerise.package3":
            return "http://stackoverlfow.com/index.php";
        default: 
            return "SomeDefaultUrl";
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of the examples above should work. I would personally use solution number two, which is simpler and more elegant. You should try to avoid using static.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use *polymorphism* here:

Instead of examining the classes package (which may vary and result in duplicated entries for subclasses) you should define an interface:

```
interface SearchEngineSelector{
  URL getSearchEngineUrl(); 
}
```

Then You have specialized sub interfaces with default methods:

```
interface GoogleSearchEngineSelector extends SearchEngineSelector{
  URL THE_URL = new URL("http://google.com/index.php");
  default public URL getSearchEngineUrl(){
     return THE_URL; 
}
```

Your classes then can implement one of the specialized sub interfaces :

```
class SomeClass implements GoogleSearchEngineSelector {
   // ...
}
```

and your code code change to:  **Nothing**
because there is nothing to do for a subclass...

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't work that way. You can write **statements** only inside `functions` in Java. And **declarations** of variables can come in `class` outside of `functions`.